# Ubuntu can't boot and install on a empty HP laptop

Tags: boot

I want to install a danish ubuntu on a reformatted SATA disk in my HP 32 bit laptop. But nothing happens. I have unpacked an iso file (ubuntu-17.10.1-server-i386) and tried to boot it from a DVD or USB Stick - but nothing happens :-( I have tried to change the bootorder in bios to force boot from CD/DVD drive - this doesn't help.

So what can I do to install linux on my laptop?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Michael Eriksen

Comment: Are you sure that you want the **server** version, and not the **desktop** version?

Comment: I know it ;-) I have tried several 32 bit versions but nothing helps :-( Any further ideas?

Comment: Did you "unpack" the ISO file and write the files to DVD or USB, or did you burn the ISO directly to DVD?

Comment: I have unpacked the isofile via my windows pc through the program 7zip and tried to install the files from a DVD or USB on the hp laptop

Comment: No, that's not the way you do it. You burn the ISO image to DVD. Then it'll boot. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto